# How do you externalize an Angular2 component with Jquery

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a little problem there, i have a component that works. Its a basic component writing 'Hello World' for now that i use in a "angular-quickstart" app.

The thing is, i want my component to be able to use JQuery.
On its own, it is fine. i imported jquery via `typings` and referenced it.

But i can't have access to it when i import my custom component from the "angular-quickstart". I import my component but there is not $ (Jquery) variable.

Is there any way to do this ? Or should i import JQuery via typings in my app as well ?

EDIT: i've been looking at this (https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples/tree/e7c7190a288a3c364701e8a04b9a3639359eb8e7) for half an hour and it seems like i should import jquery AND my component ...

Comment: read this answer about using Jquery with Angular2. hope this will hint to solve your problem or either post your code it would be better to solve your problem to others.

Comment: opps sorry forgot to post link of the answer. link is here now http://stackoverflow.com/a/35392033/5043867

Comment: Yeah i've already done that. What i don't know is use this component outside without re-importing JQuery ...

Comment: here this refer to `this` keyword or this component ?