# how to use jquery in angular 2?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-template

I know if i I need to use 3rd party library in angular 1.3 or 1.4 .I need to make directive of that thing and use that in our project .Now I am using **angular 2.0** .I want to make this in `angular 2`
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
or this
https://jsfiddle.net/2rgrmv4q/

can I use `jquery` in `angular2`.

1.How I will use 3rd party library in angular.

2.How I make auto complete of jquery in angular 2.

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/BxMcNXLjVOJBAIiBGL5Y?p=preview

// Code goes here

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector:'my-app'
  templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare one variable and put values or initilize that variable with the values that your required. in the constructor you have to define `Jquery` part . take a look at this.Here is working example for `Autocomplete` which is required to you

> http://plnkr.co/edit/dAMQc0EN6rSS4dEuTR7E?p=preview

Just put this code into the constructor :

```
export class AppComponent { 
  availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",...
    ];
  constructor(){
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: this.availableTags
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where have you created variable? would you please explain? unable to figure out?

Comment: i Have declare variable name `availableTags` inside the class and outside the constructor. and then assign some values to the variable as explained in the answer. then use the same variable using `this` in the constructor. hope now clear.

Comment: Oh great ! Got that ! But I'd like to know what was that which could also be done with `///<reference src="server url">`. And this way will it work out of constructor? I mean to say any where in the component ? or this way it has restriction?

Comment: yups :) upvote if this answer is helpful to you. and one thing more `///<reference src=' '>` is type of importing file to the .ts file. if we want to add particular file i.e javascript file we have import via this way. normally we can call it as `typings`

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about jQuery typings, you can just declare $:

```
import {Component, ElementRef,Directive, EventEmitter,Output} from 'angular2/core';

declare var $: any;
```

If you're looking for typings, you can follow this post:

[using jQuery globaly within angular 2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762720/using-jquery-globaly-within-angular-2-application)