# How use js library with jquery on angular2 (typescript)?

Tags: jquery, angular, scrollmonitorjs

I try migrate angular js to angularjs2 with typescript.

I can't understand how use js library.
I have main app.component where I want initialize some library, for example simple row:

```
$('#home').height($(window).height());
```

and initialize by `attribute data-spy="scroll" data-target="#header-navbar" data-offset="51"`

Index.html

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#header-navbar" data-offset="51" class="pace-done">

    <pm-app>Loading App...</pm-app>


    <!-- ================== BEGIN BASE JS ================== -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="assets/crossbrowserjs/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/crossbrowserjs/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/crossbrowserjs/excanvas.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/scrollMonitor/scrollMonitor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/landing-apps.js"></script>

    <!-- ================== BEGIN BASE JS ================== -->
      <script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ================== END BASE JS ================== -->
<!-- ================== END BASE JS ================== -->
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>


    <!-- Required for http -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- Required for routing -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</body>
```

general main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from 'angular2/platform/browser';

// Our main component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

and empty app.component.

Comment: simply put your logic in the constructor of your class.Have you tried yet ? and `declare var $=any`

Comment: Jquery Didn't see html element. What is declare var ? How it use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use jQuery you firstly you have to import in the index.html,
than you can initialize your code in the constructor of component

```
constructor(){
   .....
   $('#home').height($(window).height());
}
```

in case IDE shows error than you can declare `$` of any type at the top of the class like this :-

```
...some  code here 
declare var $ : any;

export class App{
..///code goes here
}
```

see also may help you

- [how to use jquery in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35392033/5043867)

Comment: Great! By still don't understand where write declare var $ : any; . I use VS 2015

Comment: you can write at the top  of class. @Mediator see my update

Comment: I can write before Component decorator

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about that but I used the same while coding